# how to plot 3 plots in a row in python

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, gaussian, lmfit

i am using a for-loop to iterate over multiple files and plots it's x-y values in Python. However, my code plots each plot in a new row. I am interested in plotting 3 plots in a single row before moving to the next line. Any suggestions would really help.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp
import glob
import os
from lmfit import Model
path=r'E:\Users\ConfocalUser\Documents\GitHub\qudi\NV_Points'
##create a function to iterate over a folder and###########################################
###########################################################################################
def getcsvfile():
    xData=[]
    yData=[]
    files=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv'))
    for file in files:
        
        with open(file,"r") as f_in: 
            reader=csv.reader(f_in)
            next(reader)  
            for line in reader:
                try:
                    float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
                    xData.append(float_1)
                    yData.append(float_2)
#                     print('x-values for file', file,xData)
#                     print('y-values for file', file,yData)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
################################plot the xData and yData for each of the files within the folder#############
#############################################################################################################
#         plt.plot(xData,yData,'bo',label='experimental_data')
#         plt.xlabel('x,y,z distribution')
#         plt.ylabel('PL intensity')
#         basename = os.path.basename(file)
#         plt.title(basename)
#         plt.show()
######################### define the function you want to fit (Gaussian-fit)################################
############################################################################################################
        xData=np.array(xData)
        yData=np.array(yData)
        mean=sum(xData*yData)/sum(yData)
        sigma=np.sqrt(sum(yData*(xData-mean)**2)/sum(yData))
        def Gauss(x,I0,x0,sigma,Background):
            return I0*exp((-(x-x0)**2)/(2*sigma**2))+Background
##################################### Plot the fit for each of the files ###################################
############################################################################################################
        mod=Model(Gauss)
        result=mod.fit(yData,x=xData,I0=1,x0=mean,sigma=sigma,Background=1)
        result.plot()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xlabel('x,y,z distribution')
        plt.ylabel('PL intensity')
        basename=os.path.basename(file)
        plt.title(basename)
        print('The fit statistics for',basename)
        print(result.fit_report())#min_correl=0.25))
        
        xData=[]
        yData=[]
```

Comment: Take a look at the [subplots demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) which demonstrates how plots can all be placed in a single figure.